# Static class members in shared library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, shared-libraries, unresolved-external

I have a class like

```
class K {
  static int a;
  static int b;
}
```

I would like to create a shared library (dll) containing this class `K`. In a cpp file compliled in the library I call

```
int K::a = 0;
int K::b = 0;
```

to instantiate the static variables. The dll does compile without errors, but when I use the library, I get the unresolved external symbol error for the members `K::a` and `K::b`. In the main program where I want to use it, I include the same header with the declaration of the class `K`, the only difference is that for the library I use  `class __declspec( dllexport ) K { ... }`  and for the main program `class K { ... }`

Probably I am doing more than one mistake so my questions would be, how can I

- tell the linker to share the static member class in the library?
- use the static class members instantiated in the library in the main program?

PS. I use Visual Studio 2008...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should use `__declspec( dllimport )` in the header in the main application.

So here is the solution. The header file (included in both the library and the main application) is:

```
#ifdef COMPILE_DLL
#define DLL_SPEC __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define DLL_SPEC __declspec( dllimport )
#endif

class DLL_SPEC K {
   static int a;
   static int b;
}
```

The cpp file in the library contains:

```
int K::a = 0;
int K::b = 0;
```

To compile the library one has to define the macro COMPILE_DLL, for the main application it shouldn't be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Link the libarary statically instead of dynamically.

Or add a global function in the DLL that returns the values.